# Disable sendmail

Tags: debian, sendmail

I am setting up a Debian web server for testing and want to disable mails of any kind being send thorugh the server. I think I just have to uninstall `sendmail`, will that be enough? Will it affect other services?

Comment: If you are setting it up yourself, why do you have sendmail installed in the first place?

Comment: I already installed the server and found out later that it didn't have to send mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail being on the server doesn't necessarily mean it will be used to send mail by the outside world. Some services may rely on it to send mail to local users as alerts. Three options:

- Make sure sendmail only listens on localhost
- Disable it in your init system (which you haven't told us what version of Debian you're running so this is left as an exercise for the reader)
- Uninstall sendmail with `dpkg --remove sendmail`